# React Slick not working

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm new to slick, react, and react-slick and I have made a new component using [react-slick](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick). When I implemented the responsive carousel and CSS (and even before that) the elements are stacked vertically as you can see in [this image](http://screencast.com/t/nu1qXpzcYRSX). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please take look at [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Please upload your codes to make the question more clearer.

Answer (score 7):

try to connect css files

```
@import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
@import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="UTF-8" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
```

and after it you can overwrite usig classes

Answer (score 6):

Refer to the official doc for correct installation here:
https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/get-started

Make sure you have completed the following steps:

1. Install dependencies:

   ```
   yarn add react-slick
   yarn add slick-carousel
   ```
2. Import CSS

   ```
   @import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick.css"; 
   @import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
   ```

Comment: Thanks, dear for saving my client.

Answer (score 6):

A few things to have into consideration:

1- Be sure to install and import the proper files

```
npm install react-slick --save
npm install slick-carousel


// Import the Component and the css files in your MyComponent.jsx file
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
```

**Note**: If you are using Typescript probably you will need to install the @types too:

```
npm install @types/react-slick --save
```

2- Remember you don't have to add **flex** or anything like that to the father container because the library already situates the elements itself, so if you have a container with **flex** remove it.

3- Be sure to pass the proper setting to the Component, especially the `slidesToShow: x`

eg:

```
const settings = {
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    };

    <Slider {...settings}>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </Slider>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's better to add you code...
Anyway here is an example of React Slick:

html:

```
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

js:

```
var ReactSlickDemo = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var settings = {
        dots: true
    }
    return (
        <div className='container'>
        <Slider {...settings}>
            <div><img src='http://placekitten.com/g/400/200' /></div>
          <div><img src='http://placekitten.com/g/400/200' /></div>
          <div><img src='http://placekitten.com/g/400/200' /></div>
          <div><img src='http://placekitten.com/g/400/200' /></div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ReactSlickDemo />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

css:

```
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  color: #333;
  background: #419be0;
}
```

from [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kirana/20bumb4g/)

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you are importing below in your js or jsx file:-

> import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
>
> import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";

Please update your Jsx like below:-

```
<div className="slider-container">
<Slider {...settings}>
            <div><img src='http://placekitten.com/g/400/200' /></div>
          <div><img src='http://placekitten.com/g/400/200' /></div>
          <div><img src='http://placekitten.com/g/400/200' /></div>
          <div><img src='http://placekitten.com/g/400/200' /></div>
        </Slider>

</div>
```

Add Css below:-

```
.slider-container {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting Slider in a div helped in my case.

```
<div>
<Slider>
</Slider>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Container div width did the trick for me

.slider-container {
display: inline-block;
width:500px
}

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and resolved it by adding below stylesheets in index.html head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="UTF-8" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
```